# Remove border in HorizontalPanel of GWT

Tags: gwt, border, uibinder

My previous programmer developed web UI using GWT's UI Binder like below. The problem is that there is border showing exactly like table.
Is there way I can explicitly specify the border=none to HorizontalPanel. I tried add class=noborder after defining noborder in the .css. It returned error HorizontalPanel can't use 'class'. Could anyone help this out?

```
<g:HorizontalPanel>
<g:Anchor ui:field="A"/>
<g:HTML ui:field="B" />
<g:Anchor ui:field="C" />
<g:HTML ui:field="D" />
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Comment: Well, indeed `HorizontalPanel` is rendered as a `table` element, but there is no border in default GWT style. Please, inspect the `HorizontalPanel` in browser's inspector to find any additional styles applied.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
class="noborder"
```

try

```
addStyleName="noborder"
```

Comment: or setStyleName("")?